# The temperature of the surface of the sun

Tags: temperature, astrophysics, thermal-radiation, sun

If I calculate the temperature of the Sun by replacing the effective frequency of the Sun (598  THz)  in Planck's curve for Blackbody radiation, the result will be 10170 K. Still, in Wien's displacement law, the result will be 5778 K, is there an answer for this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "effective frequency" here? and what are the velocities you are talking about in your comment?

Comment: To Symmetry , the first comment is not mine , the intensity of the sun light has A maximam amplitude at the effective frequncy

Comment: How are you calculating the temperature from an "effective frequency?"

Comment: Is your question related to the differece in maximum as a function of frequency and wavelength? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#Peaks

Comment: When I use the effective (f) to determine the temperature of the sun , the result =10170 degree .

Comment: When I use the effective (f) to determine the temperature of the sun , the result =10170 degree . And I can do that by taking the first derivative and equalize it to zero, and because the frequency is known , So it's easy to find the temperature , and as I said , you will find the value of the temperature is equal to 10170 .

Answer (score 1):

If you calculate the first derivative of Plancks blackbody radiation formula for finding at which wavelength or frequency the curve has it's maximum, you will get this equation (if I haven't done something wrong, wrote it down quickly):
\begin{equation}
    \text{exp}(\frac{hc}{k_B T \lambda}) \cdot \left[ \frac{hc}{k_B T \lambda} - 5\right] +5 = 0
\end{equation}
This equation is not solvable analytically. We can do a series expansion of $\text{exp}(\frac{hc}{k_B T \lambda})$:
\begin{equation}
    \text{exp}(\frac{hc}{k_B T \lambda}) \approx 1 + \frac{hc}{k_B T \lambda}
\end{equation}

By cutting of at the right point, we get an approximation, which we are able to solve by hand. The solution is something very similar to Wien's displacement law. Consequently we get the same temperature.

Comment: You have to derivative the equation according to (f) not to lamda , l mean you have to use the equation with  (f) as a variable .

Comment: You can do the same with Plancks blackbody radiation formula as a function of frequency...

Comment: Now I got your problem, the explanation for this, Maxima differ according to parameterization, read:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law
According to this, you need another frequency value... not 598 THz.